ChromeDriver always create an instance from DevTools, is posible to turn off DevTools?
I'm using Selenium and DevTools for automated testing.
But I have a website (production environment) with JavaScript like this:
ngOnInit() {

    setTimeout(() => {
        this.loggedIn = Et.a.authCheck()
    }, 500),
    window.addEventListener("devtools-opened", () => {
        this.closeWindow()
    })
}
closeWindow() {
    window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/"
}

This detects when DevTools is opened and redirects to google.com.
This behavior also blocks automation, as the Chrome driver uses implicit DevTools.
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:64021/devtools/browser/68f1fb49-8824-4fb6-a2af-83885129cd4d
I try many options, like:
 chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    #chrome_options.add_argument('--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs=false')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    #chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')  # Evitar extensiones del navegador
    #chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  
    #chrome_options.add_argument("--headless=new")
    #chrome_options.add_argument("--silent");
    #chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu");
    #chrome_options.add_argument("test-type");
    
    logger = logging.getLogger('selenium')
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    handler = logging.FileHandler("log.txt")
    logger.addHandler(handler)
        
    chromedriver_path = 'webdriver/chromedriver.exe'
    service_args = ['--verbose']
    
    #driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path, chrome_options=options, service_args=service_args)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path, options=chrome_options, service_args=service_args)


there's no point to redirecting a user based on if devtools is open.  Remove your javascript.

we can't remove the javascript, it's to avoid using inspector. Im looking for some capability in chromedriver to avoid open devtools.

devtools has to listen for commands from the driver.   Why would you avoid using inspector?  That'll help you find bugs.

A security team has block the inspector in production enviroment. I know that is not good idea for Continuous Testing. But, now we cant use the Automated scripts for regression test.
Do you think any idea for this scenary? may be modified the chrome in order to  turn off the "devtools-opened" listener.

not sure why Chrome thinks devtools is open, but that bit of javascript there does nothing to improve security.

not sure there is a "devtools-opened" event.  Are they creating a custom event somewhere?

That's right. reading deep, "devtools-opened" is only and event, not part of chrome.

you might include the code that generates that event.  Maybe there's a way around it.  Also make sure your security team isn't giving themselves a false sense of security with this silliness.
